# Pattern Factory return [object Object] in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, class, object, factory-pattern

When I use my pattern factory for my slider, it returns me "[object Object]" instead of having HTML.
[Class code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVKMQ.png)

[HTML develop tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ARRL.png)

Do you have any idea what could happen?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contructor cann't return anything, but the object he creates and returns internally. To avoid this behavior use something like.

```
   class MediaFactory {
      getContent(data, layout) {
         // your code goes here
      }

   }
```

and usage will be

```
....innerHtml = new MediaFactory().getContent(article, 'slider')
```

Comment: Kudos on actually taking the time to read the images and small print.

Comment: @ewong _"Kudos on actually taking the time to read the images and small print"_ - That's not how SO works. Hence the rules... And the comments on the question.

Comment: @Rafayel Please don't answer questions that are off-topic like this one. Just some links to images won't help any future reader.

Comment: @Andreas not my question.  But point taken.

Comment: @Andreas  My apologies on the ```Kudos...```` comment.